# Suddenly all the YouTube videos on Firefox stopped loading, when I right click I get something about HTML5 player

Tags: youtube, video-streaming, html5

This is what I receive from every video that I am trying to play on YouTube:

[image: near blank screen]

I do not understand what is happening. All videos from other websites are working fine.

What is this HTML5 player and how can I completely remove it from my computer?

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Could you include the browser you're using to help diagnose the problem

Comment: the latest version of firefox

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely an issue specific to your graphics card. Please file a bug at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core then choose the video/audio component. Paste in the information from about:support and the right people will get notified and will jump onto it immediately.

Comment: Can you paste in the graphics section of about:support here?

Comment: You should have enough reputation to post whichever graphics you would like now.